# Determining the "Best" isosceles right triangle for a series of points.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

So I have a set of points and 3 of those points are the isosceles right triangle. Now there may only be three points in which case I know the triangle or there could be many more points and I need a way to determine which sets make triangles and which set is the "Best" right triangle.

Now I know the Pythagorean Theorem but it doesn't give me an easy way to score sets of points.

Comment: What do you mean by "score of points" ? If you have $n$ points and "3 of them make an isosceles right triangle" (understood as : make an "exact" such triangle),  take all the $n(n-1)(n-2)/6$ ways one can select three points $A,B,C$ and in each case, test if the triangle is right isosceles. Is it an issue of computer implementation ?

Comment: More an issue that the dot placement wont line up exactly with the grid so some estimation of the dots center is required.  
  
Eventually it will be a computer algorithm but currently I'm doing it by hand.